# Show that if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^3$ converges absolutely.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^3$ converges absolutely.

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges absolutely, then $\lim_{k \to \infty }a_k = 0$ and so for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $|a_k| < 1$ when $k > N$.

Now for $k > N$ one has $|a_k^3| < |a_k|$ so can we use this to find out that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^3$ converges absolutely?

Comment: yes, that's the way to do this. Fine point: not for any $\varepsilon >0$, but specifically for $\varepsilon =1$ you can find $N$ such that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your $|a_k^3|<|a_k|$ to say that $$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k^3|<\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k|<\infty$$From there it is not difficult to conclude that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k^3|$$is finite.

Comment: By "From there it is not difficult to conclude that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k^3|$ is finite." do you mean that since the tail $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k^3|$ converges we have that the whole sum converges? @arthur

Comment: Yes, because what you're adding from one to the other is just a sum of $N$ many terms, and has to be finite.